# .NET C# executable throws System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program for partially replicable reasons

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My .NET, C#, Windows Forms application running on .NET Framework 4.8 started throwing the following exception, only in production (thus, in release configuration, obfuscated and protected), a few months ago.

```
System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
```

This occurs as soon as the application starts or briefly after the user does the first operation. When caught, this exception occurs just one time and seems not to affect the overall behavior of the program.

This problem affects a minority of the users base and until now I was not able to track it down to a specific user configuration.

I've always been unable to reproduce the error on my development machine, up until recently.

If I run the application *without* Visual Studio 2022 running, the exception does not occur.
If I run the application *with* Visual Studio 2022 running, the exception is thrown. VS is opened with an opened solution, is not executing any code.

Any idea about what could cause this issue? It must be something not strictly related to VS, but something that VS triggers when executed, because I'm fairly sure the users of this software aren't running VS on their machines.

Comment: Have you tried disabling code optimization and obfuscation?

Comment: What is "obfuscated and protected"? It wouldn't be the first time that an obfuscator applied a transformation to a program that's supposed to be safe, but turns out not to be. The usual applies: reduce the problem to the smallest difference you can produce, then focus on that difference. The second major thing to check for is third-party applications injecting code through DLL injection that messes with things (and no, VS itself doesn't do this, but there are many ways its presence could trigger other behavior).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Obfuscation and protection are made with .NET Reactor (Eziriz) and Sentinel Envelope (Thales). I tried disabling both with no difference in the outcome.

Comment: @MitchWheat I've tried disabling obfuscation, but not optimization. Will look into that.

Comment: If none of the major changes affect the outcome, it may well be that you've got a plain old boring bug in your application that manifests only sporadically, like a threading bug that's sensitive to timing, or a P/Invoke bug that depends on where DLLs happen to be loaded. In that case literally any difference can cause the behavior to trigger, or none at all, and your main plan of action should be reducing your application itself to the smallest code that can still trigger it. Using a just-in-time debugger can also help, but debugging an internal CLR exception has a bit of a learning curve.